# Exponential Distribution - ML estimator of λ in τ parametrization

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

I am stuck with the following problem: We know that $x_1 \cdots x_n$ ~ Ex$(1/\lambda)$ and we are given the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. We want to find the maximum likelihood estimate of $\lambda$, as well as its variance. Also we want to find a $(1-\alpha)$ - confidence interval.

I know that E $ [x_i] = 1/\lambda $ and that the likelihood is $L(\frac{1}{\lambda} | x_1\cdots x_n) = \lambda^n e^{-\sum_i x_i\lambda}$. Therefore the ML estimate should be
\begin{align}
\hat{\lambda}= \frac{n}{\sum_i x_i}.
\end{align}
However, I don't know how to calculate the expectation value or the variance of $\hat{\lambda}$ as this involes $E[\frac{1}{\sum_i x_i}]$ and I know that normally
\begin{align}
E [\frac{1}{X}] > \frac{1}{E[X]}.
\end{align}
Therefore I guess that E$[\hat{\lambda}] > \lambda$, but I don't know how I would calculate it. Thank you already.

Comment: $\sum X_i \sim Gamma(n,1/\lambda)$, then find its variance.

Comment: So var $[\sum X_i ] = n/\lambda^2$ ? I still don't see how this would help me as var $[1/X] \neq 1/$var$[X]$, right?

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable with support $\Omega$ and pdf $f_X$, then $E(1/X)=\int_\Omega \big(\frac{1}{t}\big)f_X(t)dt$, so like was mentioned use $X\sim Gamma(n,1/\lambda)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S=\sum X_i \sim Gamma(n, 1/\lambda).$ If $S\sim Gamma(n,a)$ then $E(S^t)=\int_0^\infty x^t \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)a^n}e^{-x/a}x^{n-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(n+t)a^{n+t}}{\Gamma(n)a^n}\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+t)a^{n+t}}e^{-x/a}x^{n+t-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(n+t)a^{n+t}}{\Gamma(n)a^n}$ for all $t>-n$. 
$Var(n/S)=E(n^2/S^2)-E^2(n/S)=n^2\left(\frac{\Gamma(n-2)a^{n-2}}{\Gamma(n)a^n}-\left(\frac{\Gamma(n-1)a^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)a^n}\right)^2\right)=n^2\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)a^2}-\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)a}\right)^2\right)=\frac{n^2}{a^2(n-1)^2(n-2)}.$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! In your calculation of $E(S^t)$ you forgot the $a$ in the exponent, right? So it would be $e^{-x/a}$.

Am I right that $E(\hat{\lambda})$ then is $E(\hat{\lambda}) = n \frac{\Gamma(n-1)}{\Gamma(n)} \lambda$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Great! Just one more question: will the confidence interval for $\lambda$ be just taken from the regular Gamma quantiles, i.e. from Gamma$(1,\frac{1}{\lambda})$ as Ex$(\frac{1}{\lambda}) = $Gamma$(1,\frac{1}{\lambda})$ ?

Comment: Yes, you can find the bounds for CI using quantiles for Gamma.

Comment: Thanks again. You really helped me clarify all this in my mind!